# break inner foreach loop but not all loops

Tags: php, foreach, break

How can I break out of a nested foreach loop in PHP? Or at least I think thats what I need to do. Basically I have a list of items like so

```
Item
|->Tag
|->Tag
Item
|->Tag
|->Tag
|->Tag->Tag has image
```

A set of items. Each item has some tags and some of those tags have an icon image. I want to cycle through the items, then the tags with in the items and if there is a icon use it, if not leave it blank. Here is what I have but its sets all the items to have images, even ones I know dont have tags with icons. I assume I might need a `break` in the in nested `foreach` loop? When I tried it seemed to make stuff even more off.

```
<?php foreach ($stories as $story) {

    $title = $story['content_name'];
    $desc = $story['content_social_description'];
    $image = $story['content_image'];
    $story_url = $story['content_slug'];
    $story_id = $story['content_id'];

    $tags = $story['tags'];

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tag_image = $tag['tag_image'];

        if($tag_image !== ''){
            $story_icon = $tag['tag_image'];
            //add break here? 
        }

        if ($tag['tag_type'] == 3) {
            $category = $tag['tag_name'];
        }

    }

    if( strlen($story_url) < 3){
        $story_slug = $story_id;
    }else{
        $story_slug = $story_url;
    }
?>
```

This is what one Item looks like when I loop through the tags. Again some items will have tags with no icons associated with them.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(10) {
    ["tag_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["tag_name"]=>
    string(8) "Featured"
    ["tag_score"]=>
    string(4) "2650"
    ["tag_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["tag_image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_teamcount"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tag_teamcolor"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_teamsocialprefix"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type_name"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    ["tag_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["tag_name"]=>
    string(11) "Clean Water"
    ["tag_score"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tag_type"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["tag_image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_teamcount"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tag_teamcolor"]=>
    string(9) "undefined"
    ["tag_teamsocialprefix"]=>
    string(9) "undefined"
    ["content_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type_name"]=>
    string(7) "Explore"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(10) {
    ["tag_id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["tag_name"]=>
    string(5) "Fast"
    ["tag_score"]=>
    string(4) "1400"
    ["tag_type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["tag_image"]=>
    string(17) "TagIcon.png"
    ["tag_teamcount"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tag_teamcolor"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_teamsocialprefix"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type_name"]=>
    string(9) "Exchanges"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(10) {
    ["tag_id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["tag_name"]=>
    string(12) "Sub Featured"
    ["tag_score"]=>
    string(4) "3750"
    ["tag_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["tag_image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_teamcount"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tag_teamcolor"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_teamsocialprefix"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type_name"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
  }
}
```

Basically for each item scan all the tags. If there is an image associated with a tag set the variable and move on to the next item. If there is no image, don't set the variable at all for that item and move on once all tags for the item have been scanned.

Comment: what is the problem when you put the break at the position you want?

Comment: Show a sample of your array.

Comment: break 1, break 2, etc... break 1  breaks the current loop, break 2 the one above etc

Comment: When I put `break` there it doesnt show some of the other data on the page such as `$category` but that makes sense since it breaks before. I will try reordering and break2

Comment: `Break 2` breaks the site and `break` seems to be adding icon images to items I can see by the output doesnt have any.

Comment: `$category` is in the inner for loop. so when break the inner for loop, the `$category` not set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this.

1. Reset the story_icon and the category
2. Use `$category` before the inner for each loop break.

   ```
   <?php foreach ($stories as $story) {

   $title = $story['content_name'];
   $desc = $story['content_social_description'];
   $image = $story['content_image'];
   $story_url = $story['content_slug'];
   $story_id = $story['content_id'];

   $tags = $story['tags'];

   //reset the story_icon and the category
   $category = '';
   $story_icon = '';

   foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $tag_image = $tag['tag_image'];

       if ($tag['tag_type'] == 3) {
           $category = $tag['tag_name'];
       }

       if($tag_image !== ''){
           $story_icon = $tag['tag_image'];
           break;
       }
   }

   if( strlen($story_url) < 3){
       $story_slug = $story_id;
   }else{
       $story_slug = $story_url;
   }
   ?>
   ```

> try this and let me know where is the problem if any.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by reset? I saw the category issue so I know set that before the image

Comment: because it is in inner loop, so if the break occur then the new category will be not set, the old category hold by the variable so i reset the variables.

Comment: Ahhhh I get what you are saying.

Comment: just need to know the condition where you want to break the inner loop.

Comment: @Packy, Do you want to browse whole tag array?? want to store category and image if they are??